# How to fix AWS S3 bucket mission "Sorry! You do not have permissions to view this bucket."

Tags: amazon-s3

After messing around with S3 bucket permission, I can't access the s3 bucket from AWS console and CLI. Always getting this error from the console

> Sorry! You do not have permissions to view this bucket.

Using the CLI on any s3api call, would get Access Denied.

> A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the GetBucketVersioning operation: Access Denied
>   A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObjectAcl operation: Access Denied

Anyone know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What user are you using to connect to S3? Is it the root user (bad practice) or is it an IAM user? Does the IAM user have any S3-related policies? In the console, can you add any permissions under the "Permissions" tab for the bucket?

Comment: I am using an IAM user with administrator AWS policy to create the bucket. I don't have access to the "Permissions" tab from aws console anymore. Current login using IAM user. I have not tried using root login yet.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in the end it was the bucket policy where my IP was in the blocked instead of allow access. I used a different ip and able to update bucket policy.